# How would I make sure that a string doesn't contain letters, and keep the program running if it does?

Tags: python

```
def calcwages(totalWages, totalHours):
    weeklyWages = totalWages * totalHours
    return weeklyWages

def main():
    hours = input("Enter how many hours you work")
    wage = 7.50
    total = calcwages(wage, hours)
    print('Wages for {hours} hours at ${wage:.2f} per hour are ${total:.2f}.'
      .format(**locals()))

main()
```

I'd like to make it so that if a user entered a string four hours, the program would let the user know that's not an acceptable response while running it again. I tried using while loops but I had some trouble with the checking strings for letters issue.

Comment: You should google "if else python"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with `isdigit()` but default `isdigit()` method only works for int not for float so you can define your own `isdigit()` which will work for both:

```
def isdigit(d):
    try:
        float(d)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

And then you can do :

```
def calcwages(totalWages, totalHours):
    weeklyWages = totalWages * totalHours
    return weeklyWages

def main():
    hours = input("Enter how many hours you work ")
    if isdigit(hours):
        hours = float(hours)
        wage = 7.50
        total = calcwages(wage, hours)

        print('Wages for {hours} hours at ${wage:.2f} per hour are ${total:.2f}.'.format(**locals()))
    else:
        print("please enter numbers only")
        return main()
    return total

main()
```

output:

```
Enter how many hours you work three
please enter numbers only
Enter how many hours you work four
please enter numbers only
Enter how many hours you work 3.4
Wages for 3.4 hours at $7.50 per hour are $25.50.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the flow with a `try except` block, inside a while loop.
When the entry is correct, the loop will exit; however, when the entry contains characters, it will print a message, and ask for a new entry, until a correct one is proposed:

```
def calcwages(totalWages, totalHours):
    weeklyWages = totalWages * totalHours
    return weeklyWages

def main():
    while True:
        hours = input("Enter how many hours you work")
        try:
            hours = float(hours)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("pls enter a number")
    wage = 7.50
    total = calcwages(wage, hours)
    print('Wages for {hours} hours at ${wage:.2f} per hour are ${total:.2f}.'.format(**locals()))

main()
```

Comment: As I mentioned to the answer below, this works well but breaks if I enter a letter.

Comment: Maybe it's my compiler? This is the error I get. Sorry for the confusion.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/UriWasHere/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/UriWasHere/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test.py", line 8, in main
    hours = input("Enter how many hours you work: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Comment: IDK, it looks like a gremlin error (copy/paste of special characters)? Which python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Python provides the isdigit() function that checks if a given string only has numbers.
You can use it as follows.

```
def main():
    while True:
        hours = input("Enter how many hours you work: ")
        if hours.isdigit():
            break
        print('Please only use numbers.')
    # ...
```

Note that decimal numbers won't work with this method.

Comment: This works well, but if I enter a letter everything breaks.

Comment: @uriwashere It works for me... I'm not sure how you implemented the code sample. Here's a full working example, try it out and you'll see that it works fine when you give it a letter: https://pastebin.com/s24E12xu

Comment: Unlesss... what do you mean by "It breaks when you enter a letter", are you wanting it to do a reprompt, or are you trying to achieve some other behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use `isdigit()`  - Returns true if string contains only digits and false otherwise

```
def calcwages(totalWages, totalHours):
    return  totalWages * totalHours
def main(): 
    hours = input("Enter how many hours you work")
    while  hours.isdigit() == False : 
        hours = input("Enter digits only")
    wage = 7.50 
    total = calcwages(wage, hours)
    print('Wages for {hours} hours at ${wage:.2f} per hour are ${total:.2f}.' .format(**locals()))
main()
```